# Countries' Latitude and Longitude range?

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude

Do countries have a Latitude and Longitude range?.

Is it possible to get the latitude and longitude range or boundary for each country.

UK lat and long is 51.5000° N, 0.1167° W.

What is the Maximum and minimum ,latitude and longitude i can have to be still in the UK?

For an example, i have 2 sets(a,b) of lat and long, I start at set a which i know is within the country but i don't know if Set b my destination is still within the country.

Comment: Yes, get some global shape files from somewhere and then calculate the bounding boxes.

Comment: Like John said. You can obtain data for countries here: http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/

Comment: UK minimum Bounding Box http://isithackday.com/geoplanet-explorer/index.php?woeid=23424975

Comment: But just understand there could be plenty of circumstances where multiple countries could have overlapping bounding boxes.  Country boundaries aren't always perfectly squared off, so areas near borders wouldn't really be that useful necessarily.  Ex Lat 31.304130, Long -72.127650 looks like it should fall within the US's bounding box, but it's in the middle of the ocean and should be legally in international waters, so...  Another option would be to run an identify or spatial join of some type against a world countries shapefile.

Comment: There are also "countries" (US, Russia, & Antarctica) which straddle 360 degrees of the globe -- all of Europe is "inside" the US MBR.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. It is possible to get lat/long range for each country.  The minimum and maximum lat/long is available at the below link.  Hope this helps.
https://web.archive.org/web/20150319012353/http://opengeocode.org/cude/download.php?file=/home/fashions/public_html/opengeocode.org/download/cow.txt